# Conditional rules on the fields based on jQuery.validator.addMethod

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two jQuery.validator.addMethod, named "A" and "B". 
Is it possible to set conditional rules on the fields based on different methods? For example:

```
$("#form2").validate( {
    rules: {
        inputVal: {
            //if condition = true, A:true, else run B:true
        }
    }
     ...
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to set conditional rules on the fields based on different methods?

No, you cannot set different rules based on different conditions within the `.validate()` method.  The object literal for each field can only contain a comma separated list of `key:value` pairs representing the desired methods and parameters.

However, you are allowed to conditionally set the parameter for each method using the `depends` property, effectively achieving the same thing by toggling the rule on or off...

```
$("#form2").validate( {
    rules: {
        inputVal: { // <- field name
            method_A: 
                depends: function(element) {
                    // activate/disable method A
                    return (condition) ? true : false;
                }
            },
            method_B: 
                depends: function(element) {
                    // disable/activate method B
                    return (condition) ? false : true;
                }
            }
        }
    },
     ...
});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/nL2sk069/**

---

Otherwise, you could simply write a new method that combines the functionality of methods A & B, and just evaluate your condition there.

```
var message;

$.validator.addMethod('method_C', function(value, element, param) {
    var result;
    if (condition) {
       // validate value as per A
       result = (value === "A") ? true : false;  // (pass or fail)
       message = "custom message A";
    } else {
       // validate value as per B
       result = (value === "B") ? true : false;  // (pass or fail)
       message = "custom message B";
    }
    return this.optional(element) || result;
}, function() { return message; });
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/3uheeetx/**

Comment: hi sparky, would like to ask how do i set the different error messages according to the different method (if fail)?

Comment: @ahgal, yes, just replace the message with a function and return the string you want.  See my edited answer.